# Что значит этот оператор ':=' в SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Что значит оператор ':=' в SQL и в чем разница с '='?

Comment: Это оператор присвоения. Обычный знак равенства может интерпретироваться двояко - и как присвоение, и как сравнение. И не всегда правильно. С оператором присвоения такого не бывает.

Comment: В SQL нет оператора :=

Answer (score 1):

В SQL вы можете использовать переменные связывания следующим образом:

```
variable deptno number
exec :deptno := 10
select * from emp where deptno = :deptno;
```